# CSS background-size ignores 2nd value

Tags: css, webkit

When I specify `background-size: 100% 100%` on a `BODY` element style attribute, WebKit rewrites it to `background-size: 100%`. According to the spec that would be equivalent to `100% auto`.

Why does this happen?

Comment: Are you talking about WebKit as in, not-Blink WebKit (e.g. Safari), or anything that is WebKit-based? I'm not seeing this issue on Chrome 41.

Comment: Actually it's embedded WebKit2 (WKWebView). Having a hard time to reproduce elsewhere.

Comment: OK, reproduced on Safari on my iPhone using `data:text/html,<!DOCTYPE html><body style="background-size: 100% 100%"><script>document.write(document.body.style.backgroundSize);</script>` - desktop Chrome is not affected.

Comment: Feature or Bug. Can't decide. It makes sense to set it automatically to `auto` when the body height is `0`. Maybe that's why.

Comment: Well either way it violates the spec, so...

Comment: Filed a bug https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=143191

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size#Browser_compatibility):

> [2] WebKit-based browsers originally implemented an older draft of CSS3 background-size in which an omitted second value is treated as *duplicating* the first value; this draft does not include the `contain` or `cover` keywords.

The following minimal test case outputs "100% 100%" in all other browsers, including versions of Chrome that use Blink, and outputs "100%" in Safari:

```html
data:text/html,<!DOCTYPE html><body style="background-size: 100% 100%"><script>document.write(document.body.style.backgroundSize);</script>
```

Modifying it to use the `-webkit-` prefix outputs "100%" in all versions of Chrome, including those that use Blink, which suggests that Chrome has left its experimental implementation of `-webkit-background-size`, which dates back by [more than a decade](http://www.w3.org/TR/2002/WD-css3-background-20020802/#background-size), intact:

```html
data:text/html,<!DOCTYPE html><body style="-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%"><script>document.write(document.body.style.webkitBackgroundSize);</script>
```

However, rendering tells a different story: Chrome renders according to [the latest spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-background-size) regardless of whether the prefix is used, and I haven't managed to figure out what exactly Safari is doing yet...

Comment: So I guess the "fix" is to use `cover` for now. Not exactly the same, but close.

Comment: @Erik Aigner: Does it actually render incorrectly for you, or is it simply exposing the computed style incorrectly? I realize this is WebKit, but I would be hard-pressed to believe it still renders this wrongly because MDN seems to suggest that the rendering behavior has since been updated.

Comment: Rendering is fine, as long as I don't touch the style attribute. The problem is that this is used inside an editor like environment that relies on style attributes being the actual attributes.

Comment: @Erik Aigner: Further testing produces... very confusing results. I've dealt with my fair share of IE bugs, but IE has got nothing on WebKit-based browsers.